Seeking alternative solutions: $z_1, z_2$ satisfy $z^2 - z + ai = 0,$ for $a\in \mathbb{R}.$ Find $a$, given that $|z_1^2 - z_2^2| = 1.$

Let $z_1, z_2$ be two complex roots of the equation $z^2 - z + ai =
 0$, with $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and $i$ being the imaginary unit. Find
$a$, given that $|z_1^2 - z_2^2| = 1.$

My solution:
By Vieta's, we have $z_1 + z_2 = 1$. $\quad(*)$
On the other hand, $|z_1^2 - z_2^2| = 1 \iff |z_1 - z_2||z_1 + z_2| = 1 \iff|z_1 - z_2| = 1.$
Let $z_1 - z_2 = \cos{\varphi}+ i\sin{\varphi}.$ $\quad(**)$
Then combing $(*)$ and $(**)$, we have $z_1 = \dfrac{1+\cos{\varphi}}{2}+i\dfrac{\sin{\varphi}}{2}.$
Substituting $z_1$ in to the original equation, we obtain $$\sin^2{\varphi}-\sin{\varphi} + i(2\sin{\varphi}\cos{\varphi}+4a) = 0.$$
This implies that $\begin{cases} \sin^2{\varphi}-\sin{\varphi} = 0 \\ 2\sin{\varphi}\cos{\varphi}+4a = 0\end{cases}$.
The first equation gives $\varphi = k\pi$ or $\varphi = \dfrac{\pi}{2} + k2\pi,$ both of which give $a = 0.$ Therefore, $a =0.$
For some reason, I feel that my solution is not the most efficient. It took me half an hour to figure it out and I don't think I can come up with a better approach. I'm hoping to hear alternative solutions if available to improve my skills. Thank you very much!

Lemma
Given a complex number $z = x + yi\in\mathbb{C}$, it can be claimed that $\sqrt{|z|} = |\sqrt{z}|$.
Proof
Let $\sqrt{z} = a + bi$. Then we may declare that
\begin{align*}
x + iy = (a + bi)^{2} = a^{2} - b^{2} + 2abi & \Longleftrightarrow |z| = \sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2}} = \sqrt{(a^{2} + b^{2})^{2}}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow |z| = a^{2} + b^{2}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \sqrt{|z|} = \sqrt{a^{2} + b^{2}} = |\sqrt{z}|
\end{align*}
and we are done.
Solution
According to the Bhaskara's formula, the solutions of the proposed quadratic equation are:
\begin{align*}
z_{1,2} = \frac{1 \pm\sqrt{1 - 4ai}}{2}
\end{align*}
Consequently, one has that
\begin{align*}
|z_{1} - z_{2}| = \left|\frac{1 + \sqrt{1 - 4ai}}{2} - \frac{1 - \sqrt{1 - 4ai}}{2}\right| = \left|\sqrt{1 - 4ai}\right| = 1
\end{align*}
Based on the presented lemma, the last equation is equivalent to:
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{|1 - 4ai|} = 1 & \Longleftrightarrow |1 - 4ai| = 1\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow 1 + 16a^{2} = 1\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow a = 0
\end{align*}
Hopefully this helps!

This was my approach as well. Though, it should be $-4ai$ everywhere, right?

@Ennar Yes, indeed. Thanks for pointing it out. I fixed the typos.

The sum and difference of two complex numbers have the same moduli when the complex numbers are perpendicular to each other and have equal moduli. In this case since the sum and difference have moduli equal to $1$, the complex numbers each have a modulus of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. You can use this information to determine that the product of $z_1$ and $z_2$ is $0$, giving us $a=0$ by Vieta's theorem.

$z^2-z+ai=0$ so by sum and product (i.e Vieta $z^2-sz+p=0$)
then $\begin{cases}z_1+z_2=1\\z_1z_2=ai\end{cases}$
On the other hand let $u$ on the unit circle, $|u|=1$
Then $1=|z_1^2-z_2^2|=|(z_1-ai)-(z_2-ai)|=|z_1-z_2|\implies z_1=z_2+u$
Reporting in the sum gives $z_1=1-z_2=z_2+u\iff \begin{cases}z_2=\frac{1-u}2\\z_1=\frac{1+u}2\end{cases}$
Reporting in the product gives $\ 4ai=1-u^2$
But $1=|u^2|^2=|1-4ai|^2=1+16a^2\implies a=0$

From $z^2 - z + ai = 0$, subtracting and adding the two equations for $z_1$ and $z_2$, we have
$$z_1^2-z_2^2 =z_1-z_2 \implies z_1+z_2=1 \implies z_1^2+z_2^2=1-2z_1z_2 \tag 1$$
$$z_1^2+z_2^2=1-2ai   \tag 2$$
therefore, comparing $(1)$ and $(2)$, we have $z_1z_2=ai$ and using that $|z_1^2 - z_2^2| =|z_1-z_2| =1$, we finally have
$$1=\left|z_1-z_2\right|^2=\left|z_1^2+z_2^2-2z_1z_2\right|=\left|1-2ai\right|\implies a=0$$

We have $z_1+z_2=1$, so we require $|z_1-z_2|=1$.
From the quarter-square multiplucation identity:
$z_1z_2=\frac14[(z_1+z_2)^2-(z_1-z_2)^2]$
$ai=\frac14[1-(z_1-z_2)^2]$
So
$(z_1-z_2)^2=1-4ai,$
and then $|z_1-z_2|=1$ iff $a=0$.
